# How to prevent ima ad playing on resume with exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am new to android and kotlin, I have exoplayer 2.11.3 working with the IMA extension.
It works fine, plays my pre-roll on start of video playback but on an app pause and then resume it's also playing the ad before resuming from the correct place in the HLS.

Is this as intended by the extension? 
Other than rebuilding the mediasource without ads on resume/start is there a better solution?

This is my current initPlayer fun called on resume start depending on SDK version.

```
    private fun initPlayer(){

        if(mPlayer == null) {

            mPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this)
                .setTrackSelector(DefaultTrackSelector(this))
                .build()

            playerView.isFocusable = true;
            playerView.player = mPlayer
            playerView.setShowBuffering(SHOW_BUFFERING_ALWAYS)

            val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                this, Util.getUserAgent(
                    this, "MyVideoPlayer"
                )
            )

            val videoSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(M3U8_URL))

            // Add ads to the start
            adsLoader = ImaAdsLoader(this, Uri.parse(IMA_ADS_UR))

            adView = playerView.overlayFrameLayout
            adsLoader?.setPlayer(mPlayer)
            mediaSouce = AdsMediaSource(
                videoSource, dataSourceFactory,
                adsLoader!!,
                playerView
            )

            mPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady!!
        }

        mPlayer?.prepare(mediaSouce,false,false)

        mPlayer?.seekTo(currentWindow!!,playbackPosition!!)

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Better to check ImaAdsLoader or corresponding library instead of ur own code